# Select user info from dropdown boxes and display the selected items from database with progress counter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I need to retrieve information from employees. All data is listed in dropdown boxes. All employees needs to log in to answer all questions.  They only have the one user-dashboard page. On submission all selected items are saved in the database. When they log out and log in again, all select boxes needs to display their selected items from the database, as well as the other options in case they want to change some information.

Example there is an department option.

```
<select name="department">
  <option>Finance</option>
  <option>Human Resources</option>
  <option>Marketing</option>
</select>
```

If they select the department Marketing and update the information and log out. When they log back in select box will show Marketing in the select box (as this is their saved option) with the dropdown options of Finance, Human Resources and again marketing.

How will I be able to give these items a progress counter as well to save in the database for report purposes? I then also need to add a progress bar to the forms. when making a selection the progress bar goes up by 5% until it reaches 100%. The total % of all items they selected for the day must be saved in the database I am unable to get the progress element to save its value into a variable to save to the database

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what is your question but I would guess that you're searching for a listener using `.change()` on the `<select>`

**html**

```
<select name="department">
  <option>Finance</option>
  <option>Human Resources</option>
  <option>Marketing</option>
</select>
```

**jquery**

```
$('select[name="department"]').change(onChange);

function onChange() {

  console.log('do something');

}
```